# Regex Number Range multiple ranges

Tags: regex, xsd

I'm not very good at regular expressions, can someone help me with a regex with these specifications:

Any integer between 0-365 OR 888

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for that.

Comment: Do you know different languages interpret regex in different ways? Which language you are using. Be specific

Comment: I disagree, a regular expression is a perfect tool because there's defined pattern to match. The language is xml, I'm creating a valid pattern in my XSD.

Comment: you mean `^(\d-)?\d{3}$` ? add more patterns and what it shouldn't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this pattern:**

```
\b([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[12][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9]|36[0-5])\b|888
```

You can test it [online](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Considering the clarifications, I find this question really interesting. If one considers what the lexical representation of a number can be in terms of XSD, then there are legit patterns where only regex can do it. For example, a requirement might be to prohibit leading zeroes.

Of course that more arguments can be made against regex, for a scenario such as this; if we take literally what the question asks i.e. for `any number` then floats, doubles and decimals (a bit) add to the complexity. So, let's assume any **whole** number.

I didn't spent too much time on optimizing the pattern, focused more on making it readable, but I am showing it below (in XSD the patterns are implicilty anchored start and end), along with other options used to test various implementations...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="test">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="pattern">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt">
                        <xsd:pattern value="0*([1-2]*[0-9]{1,2}|3[0-4][0-9]|35[0-6]|888)"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="uint">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt"/>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="other">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:union>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt">
                                <xsd:enumeration value="888"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt">
                                <xsd:maxInclusive value="356"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:union>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

And some XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<test pattern="0000356" uint="0000888" other="0356"/>
```

Comment: Very well done. And you were right to assume that I should have said any whole number. I was looking to regular expression to solve this because to enumerate 0-365 and then an entry for 888 would have been tedious and I'm trying to strengthen my regular expression skills.